# Extracting PCAP using Tshark

Tags: security, iot, wireshark, tshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to extract PCAP using Tshark tool. Is there any way to get the file information like source and destination IP, source and destination port and timestamp of each file extracted from the Tshark?
For example.
I'm extracting file sample.pcap with command for http :

```
tshark -q -r sample.pcap --export-objects 'http,tshark_extract_directory'
```

Following files are generated,

> %2f
>   gSEUozajoHorzUcfwjgep5-0HOV5tn4pzQS8exfGPXFOBGBQWrEcD1wKpJQk2T59
>   3h251q2c35
>   qxrWmriaPVb2cBLwxw1uR_EEnOuZR9mgVr3ReB3-1yiVm9H15-VbU3vylDw4RGW3
>   d2a42e1f7d9a1021bd7d93af414c95c4(1).php%3fq=70a9b40eb73da11445c3a3609c8241d9'
>   RSBbr6XDxZwv-i2lhZFras66SJRIL5vez28iuddGQjo94jue4fGqpAN9QPAW_yPY
>   d2a42e1f7d9a1021bd7d93af414c95c4.php%3fq=70a9b40eb73da11445c3a3609c8241d9'
>   xEztiZ7NM12Vj9c2RTB_MT0UEYH_re0UqLWZq_vBhBZGq0KGVP1BTVXxVeSy3Veo
>   d6bc1dc7da4ed54a62b93b5d0f1cc40c.swf

Extracted files seems to have no proper naming and even if I look inside the files, I can hardly find the information I needed.
Is it possible to get the source and destination ip or port for eg '3h251q2c35' file? If possible how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -T & -e option which can extract individual fields from the pcap file
Example with -Tjson

```
tshark -r <pcap_file> -Y <filter> -Tjson -e ipv6.src -e ipv6.dst -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e frame.time
```

You should get something like

```
[
  {
    "_index": "packets-2019-08-12",
    "_type": "pcap_file",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "layers": {
        "ipv6.src": [
          "xxxxxx"
        ],
        "ipv6.dst": [
          "xxxxxx"
        ],
        "tcp.srcport": [
          "1"
        ],
        "tcp.dstport": [
          "2"
        ],
        "frame.time": [
          "<time>"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I wonder why this isn't accepted as an answer? It seems to be spot on - but not even a comment from OP.